# I do not why it is not roatating?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I don know what am I doing wrong.

Write a function named rotateArt that takes two (2) parameters: imageArray and rotation. (a) imageArray is a 2D array of any dimension containing an ASCII art “image.” (b) rotation is a value that is one of the following values: 0, 90, 180, 270, 360, -90, -180, -270. A positive value indicates a rotation in the clockwise direction. A negative value indicates a rotation in the counter-clockwise direction. A value of 0 or 360 means that no rotation is to take place, but that the image is to be mirrored or flipped around the vertical axis

```
function rotateChar(char,rotation){
let rowLookup = ['^','v','>','<','|','-','|','\\','/','`','~','[','=','_'];
let colLookup = [-270,-180,-90,0,90,180,270];
let rotations = [
    ['>','v','<','^','>','v','<'],
    ['<','^','>','v','<','^','>'],
    ['v','<','^','>','v','<','^'],
    ['^','>','v','<','^','>','v'],
    ['-','|','-','|','-','|','-'],
    ['|','-','|','-','|','-','|'],
    ['_','|','_','|','_','|','_'],
    ['/','\\','/','\\','/','\\','/'],
    ['\\','/','\\','/','\\','/','\\'],
    ['~','`','~','`','~','`','~'],
    ['`','~','`','~','`','~','`'],
    ['=','[','=','[','=','[','='],
    ['[','=','[','=','[','=','['],
];
   if (rowLookup.indexOf(char)=== -1 || colLookup.indexOf(rotation)=== -1) {
       return char;
   } else {
       return rotations[rowLookup.indexOf(char)][colLookup.indexOf(rotation)];
   } 
   }

 function rotateArt(imageArray,rotation){
 rotation = parseInt(rotation);
 let newArray = [];
 let width = 0, height = 0;
 let cols =  [-270,-180,-90,0,90,180,270];
 let rowLookup = ['^','v','>','<','|','-','|','\\','/','`','~','[','=','_'];

switch (rotation){
 case 90:
    width = cols;
    height = rowLookup;
    for (let i =0; i < width; i++){
        let newRow = [];
        for (let j =0; j < height; j++){
        newRow.push('x');
     }
     newArray.push(newRow);
}

for (let i = 0; i < rowLookup; i++){
    for (let j =0; j < cols; j++){
        newArray[j][rowLookup - 1 - i] = rotateChar(imageArray[i][j],rotation);
    }
   }
    break;
default:
    break;
       } 
return newArray;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

(Formatting your code for example with a website like https://beautifier.io/ makes it easier for others to read, and therefore to help you.)

The first thing I noticed was wrong was that you are trying to iterate over arrays like the following:

```
width = cols;
height = rowLookup;
for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    let newRow = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        newRow.push('x');
    }
    newArray.push(newRow);
}
```

where `cols` and `rowLookup`, (and therefore `width` and `height`) are both arrays. Unfortunately Javascript does not work like that.

You almost certainly want to use the array's length property. You can change the first two lines of the example above to apply this correction:

```
width = cols.length;
height = rowLookup.length;
```

Here's an alternate way that would also work

```
for (let i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    let newRow = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < rowLookup.length; j++) {
        newRow.push('x');
    }
    newArray.push(newRow);
}
```

---

I had never tried doing less than on arrays before, and I found the results worth mentioning. Here's some expressions I tried followed by their results:

```
0 < []
false
```

```
0 < [1]
true
```

```
0 < [1, 2]
false
```

```
0 < [0]
false
```